# html5 wait for gps signal before run script

Tags: html, geolocation, gps

I am working on a geolocation script but I can not find the method in html5 to wait till the gps sensor gets a signal before executing the script with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition etc.

Is there any?

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` will wait for location data to be available before executing the callback.

Comment: You're right! I misunderstood the option: timeout: 20000, in getCurrentPosition function. Thought it was used for timeout in processing the excisting gps signal. Thanks.